# Average difference between two datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find the average time each customer spent on a form.

The table looks like this:

```
customerID | InTime | OutTime
```

Comment: This is pretty basic, group by query,   select customerId, avg(outtime)  from table group by customerid.

Comment: depends on what you want the average of?

Comment: What are the data types for InTime and OutTime?

Comment: Also, do InTime and OutTime allow NULL values?

Comment: I edited you question a bit, but I wasn't sure if you meant the average for each customer (i.e. you'd have an average for each customer on that table), or if you wanted to average for all customers (i.e. you'd have just one number as a result). If I made the wrong assumption, feel free to edit your question to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gives average duration in seconds - just group by id and use the aggregate avg function

```
create table #test
(
    CustomerID int,
    InTime datetime, 
    OutTime datetime
)    

insert into #test values (1,'20140101 10:00','20140101 12:00'),
                         (1,'20140102 10:00','20140102 12:00'),
                         (2,'20140101 10:00','20140101 20:00'),
                         (3,'20140103 10:00','20140103 11:00')    

select CustomerID, avg(datediff(ss,InTime,OutTime))
from #test
group by CustomerID

drop table #test
```